Overlay with iftrail
Overlay with iftrail
I want to pass one hard-coded value with total sum from column 10-15 in trailer recordat specific position; can we do the overlay with iftril? I tried by adding overlay with ifthen condition but it's not considering the condition which I gave after iftrail.
Input data:
H 000
A 010 Pune
B 020 Mumbai
C 030 Chennai
D 040 Delhi
T 000
Output data:
H 000
A 010 Pune
B 020 Mumbai
C 030 Chennai
D 040 Delhi
T 100 4
Note: 4 is the record count

Your requirements are contradictory.  You say you want to sum the value but then later you say you want the record count. Which one do you want ? Sum value or the record counter?
Since you showed the example of record-count, I  assumed that your trailer record is identified with the character "H" in position 1.  Here is a DFSORT JCL which will give the record count at position 63 for a length of 8 bytes.
//STEP0100 EXEC PGM=SORT                                       
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                         
//SORTIN   DD *                                                
ABC                                                            
DEF                                                            
EFG                                                            
H 000 A 010 PUNE B 020 MUMBAI C 030 CHENNAI D 040 DELHI T 000  
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                                         
//SYSIN    DD *                                                
  OPTION COPY                                                  
  OUTFIL IFTRAIL=(TRLID=(1,1,CH,EQ,C'H'),                      
  TRLUPD=(63:COUNT+1=(M10,LENGTH=8)))                          
/*                                                             

The OUTPUT from the above would be as follows (notice the count at position 63 has leading zeroes suppressed)
ABC                                                                      
DEF                                                                      
EFG                                                                      
H 000 A 010 PUNE B 020 MUMBAI C 030 CHENNAI D 040 DELHI T 000        4   

